# How to append data to a text file in Android?

Tags: android, file

I want to store some data in a file. The content of the file will keep increasing so I need to append data to that file.

FileOperation.java

```
package com.chinmay.callblocker;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

/**
 * Created by user on 11/11/2014.
*/
public class FileOperation {

public Boolean write(String file_name, String content) {
    try {
        String file_path = "/sdcard/"+file_name+".txt";
        File file = new File(file_path);

        if(!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        /*FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);

        osw.append(content);
        osw.close();
        fos.close();*/

        bw.append(content);
        bw.append("\n");
        bw.close();

        return true;
    } catch(IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I am using append on file but still it only overwrites.

Comment: what do you mean by "it saves one time"

Comment: @mangusta I mean it will save text first time then it won't append anything.

Comment: Try this FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void writeTobriad2(String text) {



        try {
            File file = null;
            file = new File("D:\\somefolder\\filename.txt");


            int kb = 1024;
    int mb = 1024 * 1024;

    //Getting the runtime reference from system
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    long minimum = 10;
    long memory = runtime.freeMemory() / kb;

    if (memory < minimum) {
              System.out.println(
                  "##### Heap utilization statistics [MB] #####");

              //Print used memory
              System.out.println("Used Memory:" +
                  ((runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / mb));

              //Print free memory
              System.out.println("Free Memory:" +
                  (runtime.freeMemory() / mb));

              //Print total available memory
              System.out.println("Total Memory:" +
                  (runtime.totalMemory() / mb));

              //Print Maximum available memory
              System.out.println("Max Memory:" +
                  (runtime.maxMemory() / mb));

              //System.out.println("Thread in sleep for 2 mins"+new Date());
              try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

              //System.out.println("Thread awake after  2 mins"+new Date());
    }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(text);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
//System.out.println("Done");


//TODO Auto-generated method stub
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```